# Invalid hook call - Setinterval API calls

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a self updating simple crypto tracker and i'm hit with this error:

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

This is the code (MarketData is the call API component)

> ```
> function App() {
> const openingCryptos = ['chainlink', 'bitcoin'];
> const [cryptos, setCryptos] = React.useState([]);
>
> setInterval(function(){setCryptos(MarketData(openingCryptos)); }, 3000);
> ```

Thanks

Comment: is this the whole component?